# Plotting select PCA loadings in R

Tags: r, plot, subset, pca

I have just performed a PCA analysis for a large data set with approximately 20,000 variables. To do so, I used the following code:

```
df_pca <- prcomp(df, center=FALSE, scale.=TRUE)
```

I am curious how my variables influenced PCA.1 (Dimension 1 of the PCA analysis) and PCA.2 (Dimension 2 of the PCA analysis).

I used the following code to look at how each variable influenced the dimensional analysis:

```
fviz_pca_var(df_pca, col.var = "black")
```

However, this creates a graph with all 20,000 of my variables and since there is so much information, it is unreadable.

Is there a way to select the variables that have most influenced PCA.1 and PCA.2 and graph only those?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: just wanted to give a special thanks to AmitKohli and SlowLearning --combined, your comments really helped me explore my dataset!

Comment: You are welcome!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is first get the actual table that correlates the synthetic variable w/ the real variables. Do that like this:

```
a <- df_pca$rotation
```

Then we can use dplyr to manipulate the data frame and extract what we want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
a %>% as.data.frame %>% rownames_to_column %>% 
select(rowname, PC1, PC2) %>% arrange(desc(PC1^2+PC2^2)) %>% head(10)
```

The above will organize show the top 10 most important variables for PC1 and PC2. You can run the same thing for PC1 only by changing to `arrange(desc(abs(PC1)))`, or PC2 by changing to `arrange(desc(abs(PC2)))`... and see more or less than 10 variables by changing `head(10)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the dimension that you want, you should do this:

```
library(factoextra)    
fviz_contrib(df_pca,
                 choice = "var",
                 axes = 5,
                 top = 10, color = 'darkorange3', barfill  = 'blue4',fill ='blue4')
```

with the `axes` you can choose the dim that you want to see. In this case you are seeing the dimension number 5.
[image]

If you want to see the variables and the curve that help you to choose the number of dimension, you can use this:

```
fviz_screeplot(df_pca, ncp=14,linecolor = 'darkorange3', barfill  = 'blue4', 
               barcolor ='blue4', xlab = "Dimensioni", 
               ylab = '% varicance',
               main = 'Reduction of components')
get_eigenvalue(df_pca)
```

[image]